# "Curl : (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume."

Tags: curl, gis, wget, web-crawler

**Given an online file** which I can download via my web browser.

**I run a `curl`** on it, with

```
mkdir -p ./data
curl -L -C - 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registe‌​red/netcdf/readme_etopo1_netcdf.txt' -o ./data/countries.zip
```

**I optain the following error message:**

> curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot
>   resume.

**How to fix that ?** Other downloading tools welcome.

---

Note:

- `-L`: follows redirects
- `-C -` : continues previously unfinished download

---

**Edit:** this error message appears when the file to download **already exist AND is already complete**. It also stop the ongoing script. My requirement are :

- if the file doesn't exist, then download.
- if the file does exist but incomplete, continue the download where it stopped.
- if the file does exist and is complete, **pass silently to next command**. (no fail)

**How could I do so ?**

Comment: Does the server support continuing an incomplete download? I.e. if you download a file and Ctrl+C it halfway, can you resume? If so, then what you are seeing now is definitely a cURL bug.

Comment: Yes, the server definitively accepts to resume unfinished download. However, when the download is already finished and the curl request is sent again, curl drop back this precise error 33. It should rather notice the completeness and send a success message.

Comment: I ran `curl -L -C - 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_sovereignty.zip' -o countries.zip` twice. The second time, cURL just gives `** Resuming transfer from byte position 5351381` and exits successfully without downloading anything. Is it possible your cURL is out of date? I'm running `curl 7.37.0`.

Comment: @nneonneo: could you try the same command (download, stop, resume, complete, redownload) again with this one http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip (bug is back?)

Comment: The bug appears on my version with that URL. So, I updated my answer and reported a bug to curl.

Comment: Ok, so you seriously think it's a bug. Interesting to discover the wall on which I've been hitting my head is indeed a bug. #happy?

Comment: Well, at least there are ways to work around it (see my answer).

Comment: @nneonneo, First, sorry for the earlier errror in url. I think identified the bug with this noaa.gov 308MB file, but changed to a lighter naturalearthdata.com 5MB files to save my saviors minutes of downloads. Secondly, thanks for your indeph answer, thanks for your swift bug report, that's great to move forward.

Comment: FYI: a better choice would be a file like `http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/netcdf/readme_etopo1_netcdf.txt`, which is 1.1KB but exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I edit the question / demo case.

Comment: @nneonneo: Any news from the CURL bug report ?

Comment: I didn't found the August 22 bug report on [this list](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/search/?q=%21status%3Aclosed-wont-fix+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-later+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-accepted+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-duplicate+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-out-of-date+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-postponed+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-rejected+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-remind+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-works-for-me+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-invalid+%26%26+%21status%3Aclosed-fixed), could you provide the link ? Can I support the bug-fix request ?

Comment: Ok, resubmitted there ! https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1443/

Comment: I just want to remind that in my case, added `-H 'Range: bytes=0-'` causes `-C - --output` produces such error, curl doesn't overwrite `Range` header if `-C`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried running this command twice:

```
curl -L -C - 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_sovereignty.zip' -o countries.zip
```

and got the following output:

```
$ curl -L -C - 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_sovereignty.zip' -o countries.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 5225k  100 5225k    0     0   720k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--  836k
$ curl -L -C - 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_sovereignty.zip' -o countries.zip
** Resuming transfer from byte position 5351381
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
$ echo $?
0
```

So, it looks like the "resume" is working fine. Since you posted the question back in May, it is entirely possible <s>that cURL has fixed their bug or</s> that the webserver in question has updated their support for HTTP range requests.

---

As you noted in the comments, the bug still occurs with the ngdc.noaa.gov website. I checked my curl and it is doing the same thing. Therefore the bug is still in curl.

With Wireshark I checked what is going on in the HTTP protocol. Basically, when curl makes the request to resume the completed file, the server sends back an HTTP 416 error ("Requested Range Not Satisfiable"). In the case of naturalearthdata.com, the CDN they use adds a Content-Range header specifying the exact length of the file. ngdc.noaa.gov does not add this header. Note that the addition of Content-Range in HTTP 416 responses is optional per RFC 2616.

curl uses Content-Range to determine if the download is complete. If the header is missing, curl assumes that the server doesn't support range downloads and spits out that error message.

I've reported this as a bug to the libcurl mailing list. We'll see what they say. In the meantime, here are two possible workarounds:

- Use a different downloader. I use `aria2c` often, which is a very nice command-line download utility with support for multiple connections and resumed downloads. It may make your downloads faster by utilizing more of your connection (assuming the server supports it), and I've checked that aria2c doesn't suffer from the same bug as curl.
- Use `curl -I <URL> | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f 2` to obtain the length of the file, and check that against your downloaded file size, before running `curl`.

Comment: The bug on curl mailing list didn't progress since 2014 :( https://curl-library.cool.haxx.narkive.com/CZW4rtxH/bug-curl-should-check-content-length-before-assuming-the-server-does-not-support-resume

Answer (score 2):

If the web server doesn't support requests for specific byte ranges you can't use -C and that appears to be the case with that host.

Comment: Was working yesterday. It my be related to my new location and new wifi.

Comment: Unless you're actually trying to continue an existing download, this looks like a bug to me and you should submit a bug report to the guys at cUrl. Even if you're trying to continue an existing download, it should, in theory fallback to downloading the complete file if the server does not support the Range header.

Comment: @darnir: after check, it bug when the download target already exist and is complete. The trouble is, this error it completely stop my longer makefile workflow.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, first check that the target file doesn't exist.

Comment: Existing file will not tell you if complete or incomplete, which is the cause of the bug.

Comment: Yes, it's not the bug explanation but a quick workaround to solve the problem and continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install a node version and the installation fails, be sure to delete the node downloads from

```
src (~/.nvm/src/)
```

or you might get an error when trying to reinstall them again or you might get an error like the following:

```
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

**Do let me know if it worked or else I will suggest you something else.**

Comment: What in the hell does Node have to do with this question?